# system wide api hook

Tags: c++, windows

What is the best way to do system wide user mode (NOT KERNEL MODE) api hook on Windows NT?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish?  "Best way" could vary heavily on that.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, you'd do this using [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx).  This allows you to hook into all applications on the current desktop.

There are other options, though.  [This CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx) has a lot of details on hooking mechanisms.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of hooks? You can intercept event messages via hook apis.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx) to inject your dll into all processes.
2. Use DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH handler to iterate process modules and fill import tables of modules in another process with your handler addresses of your injected dll.
3. Use [shared sections](http://www.drdobbs.com/sharing-variables-between-win32-executab/184403303) to share your data.